# Powershell - Get-MailboxStatistics | TotalItemSize -gt "40GB"

Tags: powershell, office365

i am using the below command to try and extract the mailbox sizes within our office 365 , i am then stuck trying to filter the results to include only the mailboxes which are over 40GB.

I believe this is because the below converts 'TotalItemSize' to a string and then i cannot compare to the [int] value of '40' GB however i am not compatant enough to rewrite the below!! :( I have tried alot of iterations of Where-Object 'TotalItemSize' -gt "40" etc but nothing has worked for me.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics   | Select DisplayName, @{name=”TotalItemSize”;expression={[math]::Round((($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”,””)/1GB),2)}},ItemCount | Sort “TotalItemSize” -Descending
```

thanks for any help.

19/01/17 still an issue - anyone add anything?
20/01/17 still an issue - can anyone add anything?
23/01/17 still cant solve!
25/01/17 still no resolution
1/02 HELP!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up finding out this works fine -

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | 
Select DisplayName, @{name=”TotalItemSize”;expression={[math]::Round((($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”,””)/1GB),2)}} | 
Where {$_.TotalItemSize -gt "45.0"} | Sort TotalItemSize -Descending
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the `.ToGB()` Method of the `TotalItemSize.Value` Property,

So this should be very easy though:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | ? {$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToGB() -gt 40}
```

Then add to the pipeline the properties you want using the `Select-Object`

Those are all the available options (Using `Get-Member`):

```
TypeName: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQ

Name          MemberType Definition
----          ---------- ----------
ToBytes       Method     uint64 ToBytes()
ToGB          Method     uint64 ToGB()
ToKB          Method     uint64 ToKB()
ToMB          Method     uint64 ToMB()
ToString      Method     string ToString()
ToTB          Method     uint64 ToTB()
```

Comment: i have just tried this though i thought the .ToGB() method only works in older versions of exchange and not O365 - i have tried to run the above and get the below - Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize] does not contain a method named 'ToGB'.
At line:1 char:61

Comment: Try this: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/02/27/get-exchange-online-mailbox-size-in-gb/

Comment: seems to only achieve what i can already output but i am still stuck separating the data. i have also tried putting the output into a variable and then piping that out e.g the $abovecmd =$abovecmd.TotalItemSize -gt "40.0" which then outputs the correct results - however this is missing the mailbox only outputting the mailbox size.